# Open GL (GLSL) - Directional Lighting ruins Texture

Tags: opengl, glsl

I've been working with OpenGL on a piece of coursework and I'm having a problem with my fragment shader. I am trying to add some basic directional lighting to a textured mesh. I am able to get the texture to appear fine without lighting.

[image: Mesh without Lighting]

However when I add lighting it keeps the overal colour of the texture, but removes the detail of the texture all together.

[image: Mesh with Lighting]

I'm not sure what's causing it, and I can't seem to find a solution online. Thanks for your help.

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 440

uniform mat4 uModel; //Model Location, Rotation, Scale
uniform mat4 uView; //Camera Location, Rotation, Scale
uniform mat4 uProjection; //Projection Matrix

in vec3 vPosition;
in vec3 vNormal;
in vec2 vTexCoords;

out vec3 oNormal;
out vec3 oFragPos;
out vec2 oTexCoords;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vPosition, 1) * uModel  * uView * uProjection;
    oFragPos = vec3(vec4(vPosition, 1) * uModel);

    oNormal = normalize(vNormal * mat3(transpose(inverse(uModel))));
    oTexCoords = vTexCoords;
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
#version 440

//Ins
in vec3 oNormal;
in vec3 oFragPos;
in vec2 oTexCoords;

//Outs
out vec4 fragColour;

//Uniforms
uniform sampler2D uTextureSampler;

void main()
{   
    vec3 norm = normalize(oNormal);

    // Phase 1: Directional lighting
    float result = max(dot(norm, -vec3(0,0,1)),0.0);

    fragColour = vec4(vec3(result),1.0) * texture(uTextureSampler, oTexCoords);
}
```

Comment: It didn't work... Thanks though.

Comment: Can you try removing the `vec4(vec3(result),1.0) *` part and see if you still see a texture, or is that what you've done in the picture above?

Comment: @thokra: The OP appears to use row-vectors rather than the traditional column-vectors, so he multiplies on the right. Although it's uncommon to do in computer graphics, I think that it's actually supported if you stick to this convention.

Comment: @TWT Removing the result vector 4 makes the texture reappear as in the first image.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Yeah, I completely forgot about that because I haven't seen it in a shader in years. Removed my comments as they were misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of the texture is still here. It looks like a single pixel is sampled in your texture. The issue seem to come from the "oTexCoords" values.

You may try:

```
fragColour = vec4(vec3(result),1.0) * vec4(oTexCoords, 0.0, 1.0);
```

And check if you see a Red/Green gradient across the cube.

When you remove the lighting, thus, don't use the lighting component ( "result" value ) in your shader, most compilers will remove all code that lead to the computation of "result".

"result" will be removed. So "norm", "oNormal", "vNormal" will all disappear from your shader.

The attributes locations will change, and my guess is that your issue come from the way you get attributes locations of your program and 'vertexAttribPointer' those locations.

Comment: Manged to fix it! I'd made a mistake with my vertexAttribPointers. Thanks so much.